# Can I use My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile in an access db?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba, download

I'm trying to download a file from the internet by clicking a button in MS Access.

I'm trying to use My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile as described here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1say4ws7(v=vs.80).aspx

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/temp/xml_test.xml", "C:\xml_test.xml")
End Sub
```

but the 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications' IDE that I'm typing this into seems to have no idea what I'm talking about (text just turns red).

Can I just not do this through the built in VB editor or can I simply load a library or something to make it work?

Sorry but I'm very new to VB and to Access so search results are not specific enough for me to understand - lord knows I've tried.

I'm using Access 2010 but the DB was created in an previous version - not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use any .NET libraries in Access/VBA.

I recommend you check out Pearson's code for downloading files, posted on his website. It says it's written for Excel  but it should work in Access. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DownloadFile.aspx

To contradict my first statement, technically there are actually a few .Net libraries that can be called from VBA if you know how to do it (late binding only, for one thing). I'm having trouble finding the information on that right now. And I somewhat doubt that the library you're trying to use here is one of them. If I remember correctly, some of the encryption library can be used in VBA.